# How to register Nginx as a service, after installing Passenger?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx

I need passenger/nginx to run many sites on port 80. I have installed it with its own installer (per the instructions on the nginx website. But nginx is not registered as a service. I can only run it through the binary.

I need to be able to do this:

```
$ service nginx restart
```

Shouldn't passenger have registered nginx as a service?
How can I get Ubuntu's daemon scripts to start the service?

Comment: I didn't know there were many installation methods, I just followed the instructions on the site.

Comment: @HappyDeveloper It's too early on Monday morning to get so worked up. [SF] has always been a site exclusively for System Administrators only, my apologies if you were misled. We have been frustrated by the site fragmentation as well, and have just as little control over it. I'll move this to [unix.se] for you since I think there's enough details to get an answer. I believe the answer will be that you have to install nginx using your Distro's sanctioned installer (`apt-get` IIRC) if you want the Distro's daemon scripts to work correctly.

Comment: Did you try installing using `sudo apt-get install nginx`?

Answer (score -1):

You can add the nginx init script from: http://wiki.nginx.org/Nginx-init-ubuntu , if you don't have it already. It should allow you to start/stop/restart the daemon using `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx <cmd>`